# Chromium keeps crashing on snap

Tags: snap, chromium

I have chromium installed as snap, unfortunately today I was uploading an excel file on google drive and it crashed. Ever since it, if i restart it it launches and instantly crashes. Killall -9 on chromium does not work since it is on snap and disable/enable snap packages is insufficient too.